# Django Template System

Tags: django, django-templates, frontend

I want to create beautiful modern Front-end UIs for my web app. I have a small exposure to Django. Django is perfect for the backend I am building so that's confirmed.
The issue is that whether the Django template system flexible enough to create front-end UIs like below?
[image]

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59317193/what-is-the-best-way-to-build-a-django-webapp-frontend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, The Django Temlating is fully capable of making a flexible ui. You can confidently use Django templating